# SpreadsheetApp.getUi() malfunctioning, alert Box, prompt box not appearing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google App Script which checks the email entered in a cell by the editors of the spreadsheet. If it is not a Gmail ID it deletes the cell content and opens an UI alert box with message "Please Enter a Valid Gmail ID". The script is triggered on edit. The script was working properly for many months, but now it misbehaving (the alert box does not appear, but contents or the cell are being cleared.) and I am receiving error notification

> You do not have permission to call alert (line 674, file "Code").

Replacing "UI alert" with "UI prompt" does not help either.

However the script runs properly when I (the owner of the spreadsheet) edit the spreadsheet and fails for other editors. All my other similar script with UI alert box are misbehaving and same error is notified.

Below is my script:

```
function CheckGmail()
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
   var email = cell.getValue()
   var domain = email.toString().split("@")
   if(domain[1] != "gmail.com")
  { 
     cell.clearContent()
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Please Enter a Valid Gmail ID")
  }
}
```

Anyone facing this problem? Looking for solution.

Comment: Have the other editors explicitly given scripts permission to run? Have you added other permissions in other functions in the code? You could also check the Execution Transcript to see more detailed logs.

Comment: The script was working fine and I have not changed anything. I checked that the function gets triggered on Edit and it works fine till cell.clearContent() (Line no. 9). Its only the alert box does not appear and this is where it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Google introduced a bug with a security patch on November 2nd that causes these permission errors. See the issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68846962